# How to capitalize the first letter of cyrillic word

Tags: django, utf-8, title, capitalize

Next problem:

```
>>> a = "привет"
>>> a.title()
'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'

>>> print(a.title())
привет

>>> from string import capwords
>>> capwords(a)
'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'

>>> print(capwords(a))
привет

>>> print(a.capitalize())
привет
```

With latin no problem, all works.
I am working in Windows 7 now. I think in Linux this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> print u"привет".capitalize() #call the method on the unicode object
Привет

>>> a = "привет"
>>> print a.decode('utf-8').capitalize() #decode str to unicode 
Привет
```

Comment: Thank you! When I write `a.decode('utf-8').capitalize()` in file it causes error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode...` but `a.decode('utf-8').capitalize().encode('utf-8')` works fine.